# How do you use ipython with pip --user installed libraries?

Tags: python, pip, ipython

I am going through a book which uses libraries that are not packaged through apt-get. Hence, I need to use pip, as [this](https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/installing_on_debian.html) explains quite nicely. In order to maintain stability of the core system, I am advised by the aforementioned article to use "pip --user" to install python packages.

I want to use IPython.

After reading [Manu's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922302/install-ipython-with-pip-on-ubuntu-16-04), I know how to install IPython through pip. However, I am unable to discover how to run IPython after that step, and it is unclear to me whether it will then also allow me to use the libraries installed through "pip install --user"

Hence: How do you use ipython with pip --user installed libraries?

To pose the whole, same question, in a different manner;

Manu, after reading [your answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922302/install-ipython-with-pip-on-ubuntu-16-04), this is my question:

"And then, how do you use that installed version of ipython? I'm coming from running ipython3 directly in terminal, but I need the "bleeding edge" pip version of ipython, in order to be able to use pip installed libraries in ipython. Is that possible?"

Comment: python doc at https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages

Comment: Isn't your local install of ipython in `~/.local/bin/ipython` ? You may need to add `$HOME/.local/bin` to your `$PATH`

Comment: If it's a customized location, the path needs to be added, otherwise the OS is not so smart enough to find it.

Comment: Thank you! Gribouillis's comment is the accepted answer for me: I did not understand that pip installs into that directory, and that that directory is not in path by default. However, isn't adding that to path a security risk because it would make part of the system use different alternatives? For example, the system uses "grep" but a pip installed program happens to be called grep, and therefore the system gets unexpected results and could crash? If so, I could `ln -s ~/.local/bin/ipython2 /usr/bin` specific programs.

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer. To answer your comment above you should not create links in `/usr/bin` to executables that exist below your home directory. This breaks the multiuser paradigm of linux. I think it is simpler to check now and then that the binary files installed in `~/.local/bin` don't shadow global commands. You could even write a python script to automate this checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu, `pip install --user` installs the `ipython` executable in the `$HOME/.local/bin` directory. This directory needs to be added to the `$PATH` environment variable.